# Usage of 'AD' era designation

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, latin

Considering the sentence:

> AD 1453, the city of Constantinople was conquered by the Ottoman empire.

**Is this a complete sentence?**

---

From what I understand of the situation:

The era designator 'AD' is an abbreviation for 'Anno Domini',
meaning 'In the year of the Lord'.
By that reasoning, 'AD 1453' is a complete dependent clause.

Disregarding any current practice regarding
  AD vs CE,
  factual accuracy,
  or other concerns,
is this actually a complete sentence?

What would be the recommended arrangement
for using 'AD' as an era designator
in this situation?

Alternate ways of writing it might include
  placing the era designator after the year,
  placing the words 'in'/'in the year'/etc. before the date,
  or a combination of changes.
Which of those alternatives would be the most correct way to use 'AD' as an era designator?

Comment: Agreed. Especially the last clause.

Comment: Any more context for this? I see this kind of phrasing a lot in timeline lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's deviant. The grammar of a foreign phrase in its own language tells you approximately zero about its syntax in English (or about the syntax of an abbreviation for it, which may or may not be the same).

Most commonly in modern English *AD* is used the same way as *BC*, as a post-modifier of the year. The older form, putting *AD* before the year, is also used.

But like nearly all expressions of time, it needs a preposition (normally *in* for a year) to locate a sentence temporally. (The only exceptions I can think of are phrases introduced by *last*, *this* or *next*, with the logically equivalent *yesterday*, *today* and *tomorrow*; and, colloquially, days of the week.)

Comment: Agreed. Note, however, that a lot of lists will shortcut things so you could see a great many examples of this when presented as a chronology.

Answer (score 2):

I immediately understood sentence under consideration, but would have preferred:      *Anno Domini 1453,* the city of Constantinople. . . .   Of course, the nerdlyer "*Anno Domini* MCDXCII . . . ." certainly deserves consideration here.  *Anno*, *annus* in the ablative, is, if I remember my high school Latin, an example of "the ablative of time when" and no preposition is required.

Comment: Another way of putting it is that *Anno Domini* means '*In* the year of Our Lord'. You could be more considerate to those unfortunates who have not studied Latin.

Comment: But this site is about English, and Latin grammar is irrelevant.

Comment: I certainly did not mean to be less-than-considerate to anyone.  I was trying to explain why the was no need for a preposition, indicate why "In AD 1492" would be redundant, and poke some fun at my own pedantry.  My apologies to anyone whom I offended or treated inconsiderately.

Comment: But what Colin is saying is that the meaning of the original Latin does not guarantee exact modern usage. For instance, _ad hoc_ (literal Latin meaning _to this_) generally means "for this"; _dramatis personæ_ (literal Latin meaning _the parts of the play_): More literally, "the masks of the drama"; more figuratively, "cast of characters". The characters represented in a dramatic work.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, for

> "AD 1643" Google cites 17 200 results, for
>
> "AD 1643" -"in AD 1643" again 17 200, but for
>
> "in AD 1643", 27 500.

I think that this shows that both variants are used, and that Google results should be regarded as not over-trustworthy.

The dropping of the preposition with certain temporal modifiers is common, especially in the US:

> (On) Thursday, we went to see Bryce Canyon.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is fine, but I don't think it's really got much to do with the meaning of "AD" per se. In a more 'dramatic' style, you can essentially place any time or date without a preposition such as "in", "on":

> June 13th 1981, Thatcher's plot for world destruction enters its second phase.
>
> 1:17pm, the revolution takes hold.
>
> 123 BC, the Klingonians finally leave Mars and head for the planet Copernicus.
>
> The Year of the Dragon, many fear that this will be the final year of civilisation.
>
> The Ides of March, Ceasar decides to have a cup of tea.

etc: it's not clear there's anything terribly special about dates with "AD" from this point of view.

Comment: Listed like that, however, it would be more correct to use a colon. As in "June 13th 1981: Thatcher's plot ..." or "123 BC: the Klingonians ...", rather than using a comma.

Comment: Well, it's more "correct", *if* you are working to a style guide or editor who specifically imposes that rule. For the sake of the examples here, I choose not to impose that rule.